# Mutt -> Compose -> Some kind of alert?

Tags: mutt

When replying to some certain emails, I usually have to add other recipients to the list. But unfortunately, I often forget to do so.

Thus, my question: is it possible that after leaving the editor and arriving at Mutt's Compose section (where you can actually add someone with `t` or `c` hotkeys), there would be some kind of additional message in the status line? Or [dependent on the recipients list] some script could be launched? Or any other idea that jumps to you? Something with the hooks may be? (Not that I know much about them.)

So, would be very grateful for any hint here :) (I already tried to play with the editor itself, to launch an external script when leaving it. But it gets very noisy: I need this kind of reminder only if contacting certain people, actually, and I can't add them blindly or always, too).

Comment: probably a `set editor=somethingcustom` wrapper that then runs the real editor then parses what that editor returned for the addresses you want to warn on (or automatically adds said recipients, maybe)

Comment: Thanks, @thrig, in some sense you were right -- I now added the solution that seems be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in Mutt mailing list, `set edit_headers` [can](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#edit-headers) actually be the solution here.

Because of this preference, email addresses will be present in the editor while editing the message. Which means that if your editor for composing emails is Vim, then you can create something like this (and add it to $VIMHOME/ftdetect/mail.vim):

```
autocmd BufEnter *mutt-* call BeAware()
function BeAware()
    if search('personX@gmail.com')
        !alert 'Add Y, Z'
    endif
endfunction
```

Which will launch an external script `alert` with some message if this specific string 'personX@gmail.com' will be present in this Vim's buffer.

Works for me :).